# How to restore Plone 3?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

I have a folder backup of a plone 3 instance and I want to run it in a VirtualBox with Debian 5. I installed a fresh plone 3.3.5 into */usr/local/Plone* as root with the unified installer and I can start it with *./bin/plonectl start*. So what are the next steps? The folder structure of the backup looks like:

```
plone
- bin
- devel
- develop-eggs
- downloads
- eggs
- fake-eggs
- parts
- patches
- production
- products
- src
- theme
- var
- versions
- base.cfg
- bootstrap.py
- build.cfg
- devel.cfg
- production.cfg
- windows-devel.cfg
- windows-production.cfg
- windows-settings.cfg
```

The original of this backup used varnish and a lot of instances but I only want to restore it with a minimal setup without this stuff.

Comment: The answer to this depends on how your old buildout is done (are you using released add-ons? have you some development activated products? are you using mr.developer or what?).

Enhance you question with your `buildout.cfg` file (or with all your `.cfg` files sources).

Comment: Yes released add-ons are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was your previous Plone 3.x version 3.2 or later? If so, both old and new use buildout for configuration management. If so, the general plan is:

1) Copy the eggs, develop, zcml and versions directives from old to new. Copy the `src` and `products` directory from old to new.

2) Run buildout. Resolve problems that occur.

3) Start your new Plone and see if it functions. Resolve problems.

4) Stop you new Plone and restore the Data.fs file from the old system to overwrite the new Data.fs (under `var/`). Resolve problems.

The "resolve problems" notes may be insignificant or non-existent if old and new versions are the same. If they aren't, you may need to update some add on package version.

If you're updating from < 3.2, see the guide for [updating from non-buildout systems](http://docs.plone.org/manage/upgrading/non_buildout_to_buildout_upgrade.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The version was 3.3.5